# Is there an elegant way to set a shell variable to the contents of a file?

Tags: shell-script, shell, io-redirection

Say I have some configuration data in a file `config`. For convenience, I'd like to load this data into a shell variable, `CONFIG_DATA`.

Obviously I can do:

```
CONFIG_DATA="$(cat config)"
```

But this kinda feels like a [useless use of `cat`](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html) to me. Is this the only way to do this? Or is there a more elegant way to do it?

Answers should prefer POSIX but may use any shell.

Comment: Reading an entire file in memory like this is almost always a bad idea, regardless of how you write it.

Comment: @SatoKatsura in some cases very true. however for the purpose of this question, you may assume that the file is super tiny, so it's not a major problem.

Comment: @SatoKatsura: why?

Answer (score 23):

In Bash and the Z shell, at least, there is a faster way:

```
CONFIG_DATA=$(<config)
```

To quote from the Bourne Again shell's man page:

> The  command  substitution  $(cat file) can be replaced by the equivalent but faster
>          $(< file).

Comment: I'd not consider this a good option. Whatever are OP's feelings towards useless use of cat, the OP's example is simple enough that most Bash users would understand it. It's also quite portable. Now `$(<file)` is a lot less common, so it might result in much more WTFs; and speed gain from this operation, if such configuration is to be loaded to a variable, is probably negligible

Comment: @MatthewRock note that a lot of very bad practices are common and familiar. The useless uses of cat are one example, `for i in $(cat file); do ...` is another. That they are common is no reason to keep using bad tools. Which is not to say that this particular use of cat is a bad tooi, I'm not sure if there's a more portable way. Just saying that common & familiar != good.